# How to improve emacs performance when view large file?

Tags: emacs

Emacs sometimes hangs when viewing large file. But it is fast with `(global-font-lock-mode -1)`.

I'm using a fork of Prelude.

Emacs version: 24.3 cocoa
System: OS X 10.8.4

Update: I found `(setq jit-lock-defer-time 0.05)` is a method to improve the scrolling speed.

Comment: You've anwered your own question. font-lock is slow. Also, `find-file-literally` is good since it puts you in fundamental mode.

Comment: @abo-abo Then your recommendation is to disable `font-lock-mode`?

Comment: @abo-abo My large file is about 8000 lines. I think it is normal.

Comment: I usually use `find-file-literally`. It disables not only font-lock, but also the major-mode. I can call it from dired when I see that the file size is large.

Comment: The speed can be influenced by so many things it's hard to tell.  But 8000 lines is not "too large", so you can consider this problem as a bug and report it accordingly.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

To help with large files, I've installed my own `find-file-hook` which turns on fundamental mode (avoids font-lock), turns off undo, and makes the buffer read-only just to avoid any accidental changes (making unnecessary backups of large files).

```
(defun my-find-file-check-make-large-file-read-only-hook ()
  "If a file is over a given size, make the buffer read only."
  (when (> (buffer-size) (* 1024 1024))
    (setq buffer-read-only t)
    (buffer-disable-undo)
    (fundamental-mode)))

(add-hook 'find-file-hook 'my-find-file-check-make-large-file-read-only-hook)
```

Obviously adjust the threshold value as you see fit.

Comment: Thank you. But I also want to edit this file. You can see my above description of a "large" file.

Comment: @goofansu Sure, just take out the setting of `buffer-read-only`... glad it works for you

Comment: Just using `(linum-mode -1)` after the checking size is enough, if not, adding `(font-lock-mode -1)` would be.

Comment: It will treat all images and pdfs larger than specified value to be opened in fundamental mode.

Answer (score 18):

If you need to work with really large files, you can use the [View Large Files](https://github.com/m00natic/vlfi) package which allows "viewing, editing and searching in large files in chunks." After `require`ing the package open large files with <kbd>M-x vlfi</kbd>.

Answer (score 4):

I usually unroll long lines and indent by tags (like HTML, XML, JSON).

In order to make such operation possible I add:

```
(setq line-number-display-limit large-file-warning-threshold)
(setq line-number-display-limit-width 200)

(defun my--is-file-large ()
  "If buffer too large and my cause performance issue."
  (< large-file-warning-threshold (buffer-size)))

(define-derived-mode my-large-file-mode fundamental-mode "LargeFile"
  "Fixes performance issues in Emacs for large files."
  ;; (setq buffer-read-only t)
  (setq bidi-display-reordering nil)
  (jit-lock-mode nil)
  (buffer-disable-undo)
  (set (make-variable-buffer-local 'global-hl-line-mode) nil)
  (set (make-variable-buffer-local 'line-number-mode) nil)
  (set (make-variable-buffer-local 'column-number-mode) nil) )

(add-to-list 'magic-mode-alist (cons #'my--is-file-large #'my-large-file-mode))
```

Note that I don't use `find-file-hooks` as `magic-mode-alist` usually empty and have priority. If I add `find-file-hooks` it first validate  XML file by `nxml-mode` and then switch to `fundamental-mode`.

I split line by regex, for XML it: `C-M-% >< RET >NL< RET !`.

After Emacs split long lines - it is possible to enable many `*-modes` and re-indent code.

Comment: this answer helped, but for me disabling `bidi-display-reordering` was enough

Comment: @gavenkoa, Thanks for this config. I tried this config but it doesn't work well when I have `(global-display-line-numbers-mode)` in my init.el. I also tried changing that to `(add-hook 'find-file-hook #'display-line-numbers-mode)` so that it doesn't interfere with your config but still it doesn't work. Could you suggest a better approach?

Answer (score -1):

it may be trick workaround
M-x shell
then
less your_large_file.txt
and you can proceed

Comment: Thanks, I'm using spacemacs now. When opening a large file, it will warn me in the minibuffer.

Comment: `less` wants a better terminal than the dumb terminal provided by `M-x shell`.  `M-x term` would work.